# How to make N prefix work with SQL Server Upsert Statement?

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, pyodbc

I have the following SQL being sent from pyodbc using bound parameters.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2
        WHERE N'transientkey' = N'67'
        )
    INSERT dbo.tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2 (
    N'transientkey, nfid, active, applicationnum, modstamp, source_database_tablename_for_kafka_connector, source_identifier_for_kafka_connector'
    )
    VALUES (
    N'''67'', ''5'', ''1'', ''52'', ''2022-10-01 03:28:25.000372'', ''tapplicationcmsnegativefactors'', ''transientkey'''
    )
ELSE
    UPDATE dbo.tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2
    SET N'transientkey = ''67'', nfid = ''5'', active = ''1'', applicationnum = ''52'', modstamp = ''2022-10-01 03:28:25.000372'', source_database_tablename_for_kafka_connector = ''tapplicationcmsnegativefactors'', source_identifier_for_kafka_connector = ''transientkey'''
    WHERE N'transientkey' = N'67';
```

I am unsure why but when trying to execute this code, an error shows next to the set clause in SSMS. What can I do to make this sql execute successfully but still retaining the N prefix so I can make it work with pyodbc.

I was expecting this code to execute successfully seeing as removing the N prefix allows the code to execute.

Included the python code below.

```
import pyodbc

# Auth.
server = ""
database = ""
username = ""
password = ""

# Set up the database connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={"SQL Server"};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

ls = [
    "transientkey",
    67,
    "transientkey, nfid, active, applicationnum, modstamp, source_database_tablename_for_kafka_connector, source_identifier_for_kafka_connector",
    "'67', '5', '1', '52', '2022-10-01 03:28:25.000372', 'tapplicationcmsnegativefactors', 'transientkey'",
    "transientkey = '67', nfid = '5', active = '1', applicationnum = '52', modstamp = '2022-10-01 03:28:25.000372', source_database_tablename_for_kafka_connector = 'tapplicationcmsnegativefactors', source_identifier_for_kafka_connector = 'transientkey'",
]


# Execute SQL
def exec_sql(kv, join_kv, col_inst, val_inst, val_upd):
    cursor.execute(
        "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2 WHERE ? = ?) INSERT tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2 (?) VALUES (?) ELSE UPDATE dbo.tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2 SET ? WHERE ? = ?", kv, join_kv, col_inst, val_inst, val_upd, kv, join_kv
    )

exec_sql(str(ls[0]), str(ls[1]), str(ls[2]), str(ls[3]), str(ls[4]))
```

Comment: You *only* need the `N` prefix before each and every single Unicode-based **value** - not before column names (in your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements).....

Comment: Is `N'''67'''` intentional? Do you really want a integer value wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: @MartinSmith Went ahead and included the python.

Comment: I'm not a python developer but looks like you are trying to parameterise TSQL language elements which don't support it. Column names should be part of the SQL not passed in via `?`

Comment: @MartinSmith The reason I'm using ? here is to prevent SQL Injection attacks from occuring from the python code. Bound parameters like ? in pyodbc prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up parameters and dynamic SQL.  You can't change the structure of the SQL with parameters, so this

`tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2 (?) VALUES (?)`

Needs to be done with string interpolation (accounting for SQL injection vulnerabilities) before the string with parameter markers `?` is sent to cursor.

> The reason I'm using ? here is to prevent SQL Injection attacks from occuring from the python code.

Just can't do that.  If you want to avoid dynamic SQL you can have a number of static SQL queries with with parameter markers for the data, like

```
... INSERT tApplicationCMSNegativeFactors2 (transientkey, nfid, active, applicationnum, modstamp, source_database_tablename_for_kafka_connector, source_identifier_for_kafka_connector) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ...
```

Comment: I noticed the example you provded was for an insert, can you provide an example for an upsert by chance?

Comment: @randomguy2443 have a go... the information above should be enough for you to work it out.